# How to use command 'wp post create' in wp-cli properly?

Tags: command-line, wp-cli

I need to create a single post with title, content and excerpt with this command as it's described in the utility documentation. Could you please show me an example of how to use it? I couldn't find nor in official documentation neither on Google.
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki

Comment: There are no examples how to create a post.

Comment: I never used it, but found it within 20secs.: `wp generate posts --count=1000` generates 1k posts for you. Just read yourself please.

Comment: There is also a command `wp post create`, that's what I am asking about. I don't want to generate dummy posts, I need to create a single post with title, content and excerpt.

Comment: So then update your post with an info and a link and we start from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type `wp help post create` you will get all the info you need.

Example:

```
wp post create --post_type=page --post_status=publish --post_title='A new page'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the code for the `create` method](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/master/src/php/wp-cli/commands/internals/post.php), you'll see that it takes 2 parameters:

```
    public function create( $args, $assoc_args )
```

`$args` doesn't seem to be used - `$assoc_args` is the array passed to the [`wp_insert_post` function from WordPress core](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post). The linked Codex page explains the array parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have many post to create, you can create a dedicated folder with all your posts as text documents, using `post_title` as the txt file titles.

In this very same folder, create a bash file named `wp-post-create--loop-files.sh` with the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=*.txt
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # TEXTFILE = $f
  # take action on each file. $f store current file name
  # cat $TEXTFILE
  wp post create "$f" --post_category=3 --post_title="$f" --user=3 
done
```

Then you can create all your posts in a blink by executing `sh wp-post-create--loop-files.sh`.